# Problems with using alphabet selectors in regex

Tags: python, regex

My String looks like this:

```
"Jothijohnsamyperiyasamy"
```

I want only `"Jothijohnsamy"` from the above string. The Regular expression,

```
'Jo\w+samy'
```

prints `"Jothijohnsamyperiyasamy"`, but I want only `"Jothijohnsamy"`. Any Ideas?

Comment: Make the `\w+?` non greedy `Jo\w+?samy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try non-greedy match:

```
>>> re.compile(r"Jo\w+?samy").match("Jothijohnsamyperiyasamy")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='Jothijohnsamy'>
>>> _.group()
'Jothijohnsamy'
```

The `+?` token means "match 1 or more times, but as few as possible. Without the question mark it means "match 1 or more times, as many as possible".

Another straightforward example: For the string `"aaaaaa"`, the regex `a+` matches all characters, but `a+?` matches only one (as few as possible), and `a*?` matches none.

Comment: Thanks.@iBug  Actually I have a string like this.          """JothiNewsamyJothiPeriyasamy\n
    Josamy\n\n

     Jo  samy""".      The output Should be ['JothiNewsamy','JothiPeriyasamy','Josamy','Jo samy']. How to write a regular expression for this?

Comment: @JothiPeriyasamyManoharan Use `compiled_re.findall()`, and change `\w+` to `.*?`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked with this one: `re.findall(r"Jo[\w\s]*?samy" `